# Gallery pick only images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

i want to pick an image from the gallery, but i want the gallery to only show images. I create my intent like this, but i still see videos on some devices

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
```

**EDIT:**

for kitkat devices i build the intent like this.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: this link is about loading bitmaps from file into a gridview

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this one    

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) 
{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
startActivityForResult( DialogsFragment.this, 
Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED); 
} 
else 
{ 
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); startActivityForResult( DialogsFragment.this, intent,GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED); 
}
```

Comment: this is actually the same i do, without setting the mime type

Comment: Have to put condition version wise

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("image/jpeg");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      startActivityForResult(
        DialogsFragment.this,
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED);

     } else {

     
      Intent intent = new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

      startActivityForResult(
        DialogsFragment.this, intent,
        GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);

     }

Comment: Jatin update your answer instead of pasting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add conditions based on OS version

Try this    

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(DialogsFragment.this,
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(DialogsFragment.this, intent,
                        GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
            }
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 different answers to this question @Jatin ?